# Unable to start any kafka processes

Tags: apache-kafka

The instructions for running kafka from the quick start page are not working for me.

http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html

Kafka builds fine

```
05:55:01/kafka-0.8.1-src:58 $sbt package
[info] Set current project to kafka-0-8-1-src (in build file:/shared/kafka-0.8.1-src/)
[info] Packaging /shared/kafka-0.8.1-src/target/scala-2.10/kafka-0-8-1-src_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 17, 2014 5:55:07 AM
```

But does not run fine..

```
05:55:07/kafka-0.8.1-src:59 $bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Similar errors occur for kafka-server-start.sh and all the other scripts inside bin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You downloaded kafka-0.8.1-src.tgz from download page. The instructions on quickstart link are meant for Binary download . Download one from the Binary downloads section of http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html page. Now try .It should work. 
Or if you want to build from the src.tgz package you downloaded, then run `./gradlew jar`. It will download all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem On Windows 10, What i have done is :

Don't download/install Zookeeper separately, download only  kafka_2.12-1.1.0 (or higher version)

1. Create temp folder , ( like this E:\DevApplications\kafka\temp)
2. Open zookeeper.properties ( i have it @ E:\DevApplications\kafka\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\config)
3. Update dataDir (for me : dataDir=E:/DevApplications/kafka/temp) Note the forward slash
4. Open CMD and run zookeeper-server-start.bat with zookeeper.properties as second parameter like

`.\zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties`

5. Once zookeeper is started start kafka server by typing

`.\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the Chandra Kant solutions, if you have proxy connection in your network then please use the below command

```
./gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=<PROXY-HOST> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<PROXY-PORT> jar
```

Thanks @Chandra kant it helped me a lot

Comment: No, no proxy connections

Answer (score 0):

You can also reach this exception if you try starting Kafka 0.9.0.0 running a java version less than java 1.7. Set your **$JAVA_HOME to 1.7 or above** and make sure `JAVA_HOME/bin` is on your classpath.